# Swift 2 - Update UITableViewRow in auto layout to change its height on button tapped in cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios8, swift2

I am using self sizing cell method to auto height in my tableview cell as my description text is variable(can fit in 1 to 5 rows). It is working fine.

[Self Sizing Cell iOS 8](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/)

I also want that on button click inside the cell text of the description should be cleared and the row height should decrease. For this I have implemented following delegate to update description text to empty and than call a delegate to my tableview to update the row. but instead of resizeing and emptying the text in the description the text just goes back to description.

```
var delegate:UpdateRowDelegate?
@IBAction func btnTestTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.descriptionLabel.text = "-"//!self.addressLabel.hidden

    if delegate != nil {
          delegate!.updateRow(self)
    }
}
```

> Protocol

```
protocol UpdateRowDelegate{
     func updateRow(cell:UITableViewCell)
```

}

> Update row delegate implemented in table View controller

```
func updateRow(cell: UITableViewCell) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

I am new to swift

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will run again and it will probably set your description to the original text.